# How do I register QSerialPort in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtserialport

I would like to register `QSerialPort` as a non-instantiable type in QML so that I can use `QSerialPort`'s ENUMs.

I tried to register `QSerialPort` in my `main.cpp`:

```
 qmlRegisterType<QSerialPort>("com.myProject", 1, 0, "serialPort")
```

I get the following error:

> /Users/user/qt/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Headers/qqml.h:234: error: incomplete type 'QSerialPort' named in nested name specifier
>       QML_GETTYPENAMES
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Any hints appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Did you `#include <QSerialPort>`?

Comment: indeed, I forgot to include QSerialPort.... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include [`#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html) and don't forget to add `serialport` at `.pro` file:

```
QT += serialport
```

Works fine for me.